# Why wont my emitter render?

Tags: rendering, particles

I have made 3 emitters in my render. 2 of those are hair - > group emitters. Of those 2, 1 is trees and the other is rocks. Both are groups rock / tree with the emitter of landscape. Landscape and trees are both rendering. Rocks are only showing in viewport but not in render. Rocks, have a texture that is working, is check to show rendered 100%. Still not appearing during render at all.

Comment: can you upload you file?   http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: On the particle properties Render panel is Emitter checked?  If not a file can you attach an image of the non working particle settings?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1650" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1650/)

Comment: Have you checked the scene panel? If you want all the objects to show in the render, you have to select all the corresponding layers that are included in the viewport. If everything is selected already, check the checkbox that said `use hair`. If all of those are on a plane it's best to use 'hair' option over that of 'emitter.'

Comment: they're all on the same scene and they are all hair particles. When I said emitter I'm just referring to the "Mountain" in this scene which is the emitter for the hair particles of all 3 "hair" items.